# Line inputs and sound quality

Tags: audio-interfaces, preamp, line-level

Ive been recording my guitar from the line out of a two notes captor into the line in of my presonus audiobox itwo via a trs cable.

I'm not 100% happy with what I am hearing as it sounds like the upper mids and highs are missing, killing all presence in the sound.

My question is, I know Mic preamps can make a difference to sound, but would the line in share the same properties and would sound quality increase with a different interface / better preamp?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

you will never get the finger sound goodness in DI, why not use stereo technique, DI on left and Mic on right and blend it together for both high detail mic sound and clean DI sound. Most pro do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably a Two Notes Torpedo Captor.  That one is supposed to be used instead of a cabinet on a guitar amp.

A "Line In" is after the mic preamp.  There is not much happening here any more, so exchanging this for a different interface will not likely make a significant difference.  You either want to post-process your signal with additional EQ or similar or so something different with the Captor and/or the amp it is connected to.

Comment: Yeah signal chain is - guitar - > Tsl60 - > captor - > audiobox itwo.  I've tried this also with a cab and sm57.  Is it usually for recorded guitar to lose presence once recorded / miked?